# start a service in onCreate of Application

Tags: android, service, android-service

I am trying to start a service when my app begins, and I need it the service to restart, incase a user decides to force close the service, even though the app is running(its ok, for him to force close the app, but i need to prevent closing of service while the app is running).

So i went about extending the Application class, and this is what I am doing to start the service...

```
ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            Log.d("start","ok");
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        }
    };
    bindService(new Intent(this,DueService.class), conn, 0);
```

This, however, does not start the service. Though, using startService seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `bindService()` from an `Application` is pointless, as you will never be able to call `unbindService()`.

Best, of course, would be for your service to only be in memory if it is actively delivering value to the user, instead of just because some other component of your app happens to be loaded. As it stands, you are headed down a path towards leaking this service, if you go with your plan of using `startService()` from the `Application`. There is no real concept in Android of "the app is running" as a lifecycle construct, so you will not have a logical time to stop the service.

(BTW, while `Application` has an `onTerminate()` method, it will never be called)

Comment: so how would you suggest, that i can keep fetching live data from server, and if i cannot fetch the data, then the app cannot run properly. so i have 2 options now, either, to have the app crash, or to restart the service.

Comment: What is the issue if you use service without binding service that means as startService(intent); ?

Comment: @Amit: call `bindService()` and `unbindService()` from each of your activities. Or, call `startService()` from your entry point activity (or, possibly, the `Application`) and keep track of when your activities come and go, so you can shut down that service with `stopService()` when it is no longer needed.

Comment: This is only true if the service started from binding. If however the service started by calling ‘startForeground’ method, unbinding won’t do anything to it. It will continue running until stopped self by calling ‘stopForeground’. Correct me if I’m wrong but I believe that having binding won’t prevent the service from being stopped in this scenario

Comment: @MikeKeskinov: A started service via `startService()` or `startForeground()` remains started until manually stopped, regardless of whether the service was also bound/unbound.

Comment: @CommonsWare Correct. So in this case we don't care about the fact that "we never be able to call `unbindService()`". So in this case we can safely bind service from `Application`.  Sounds right?

Comment: @MikeKeskinov: You can always safely bind a service from the `Application` context. In fact, that is the *only* `Context` I consider to be safe to use for `bindService()`/`unbindService()` calls. "I believe that having binding won’t prevent the service from being stopped in this scenario" -- if you call `stopService()`/`stopForeground()`, but there is still an outstanding binding, IIRC the service is still running (i.e., `onDestroy()` will not be called). It's been *ages* since I played with that scenario, though.